# How to determine the time constant from an RL circuit graph?

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, time-constant

I have an RL circuıt and this is the RL circuit's input and output graph.
How can I fınd the time constant in the graph using the cursor?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your circuit

Comment: @esk - Hi, FYI I have rolled-back (i.e. reversed) your last edit, which removed the images you had added. After adding such important details, and especially after other site members have used them in an answer, they should not be removed - this could be considered as "vandalism". Thanks.

Comment: @esk - I see you *again* deleted part of your question, so I have again reversed your deletion and locked your question to prevent further vandalism, by the deletion of relevant information from it.

Comment: @esk - At your request the question has been unlocked, as you have stated that you wish to make an edit for clarification. Please note that only *improvements* to the question and which do not invalidate the existing answer(s), will be allowed. Any other changes will, again, be reversed. FYI you are not currently allowed to suggest edits to the answer(s) yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @esk it seems your question is fully answered so, are you happy about this? I ask because you appear to want to make changes that nobody else seems to understand. Please realize that once you have received at least one answer, you have a "responsibility" to ensure that any new changes made to your question don't invalidate answers already provided. So, if you still want to change the question, please ask me so we can figure out how this can be done with minimal effort whilst still allowing the given answers to be valid (maybe with some minor modification).

Answer (score 6):

> *how can ı fınd tıme constant in graph with use cursor*

Move your cursor to the point in the red circle below: -

[image]

That's equivalent to 1 time constant as per the purple trace in the graph below: -

[image]

Image from [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/lr-circuits.html).

And, from your graph I estimate the time constant to be 0.5 μs whereas, in your circuit it is clearly numerically 0.44 μs: -

[image]

So, move your cursors to where I suggest and, get better numbers than those I had available.

---

What Scott is alluding to in comments is worth putting in the answer: -

[image]

So, both the initial slope of current and the 37% decay point predict the time constant.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Did you actually read my answer where I specifically said this: `Move your cursor to the point in the red circle below`?

Comment: If you move left cursor to t = 0 and move the right cursor to 0.37 x 2 amps, then the time position difference between the two cursors is the L/R time constant.

Comment: Also, a perfect tangent of the decay at t=0 will intersect with the x axis at t=tau.  you can also get it from the slope of the log plot

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  For completeness, the slope of Aexp(-t/tau) at t=0 is -A/tau, and the value at t=0 is A.  Given the point (0, A), you can plug this in to the point slope line formala (y-y1)=m(x-x1) to get y=-(A/tau)t+A, and it's then clear that y=0 at t=tau